# checking date on the basis of multiple format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below lines of code for checking date format on the basis of multiple date formats like

```
           function checkValidDate(dateValue)
           {
                var dateFormat = getDateFormat();
                   switch(dateFormat)
                   {
                     case "d-m-Y":
                     var regex = /^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;
                          if(dateValue.match(regex))
                              return true;
                           else
                              return false;
                     break;

                     case "m-d-Y":
                     var regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[-/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$/;
                          if(dateValue.match(regex))
                              return true;
                           else
                              return false;  
                      break;

                    case "Y-m-d":
                     var regex = /^(19|20)\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012]\d(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))$/;
                          if(dateValue.match(regex))
                              return true;
                           else
                              return false;  
                      break;
                   }
           }
             $("#dobfield").blur(function(){

                  var dob = $("#dobfield").val().trim();
                  var check = checkValidDate(dob);
                  if(check ==false)
                   alert("wrong");
             });
```

There are three formats accepted in this project "d-m-Y", "m-d-Y", "Y-m-d".
Now I am trying to check whether the date entered is in valid regular expression format or not on the basis of presently selected date format.

The above code is not working!!! Please help me!!!

Comment: Yes .... It is  Y-m-d

Comment: What does “ The above code is not working!!!” mean? Do you get any error messages? What is the observed vs. desired behavior?

Comment: There is a table in database which is storing one of three format in it. let us suppose in that table is "m-d-Y" currently... so it will check only "m-d-Y" in the switch condition. also it will check regular expression validation

Comment: @Nida can you post the html code that you have used and also where is the getDateFormat function?

Comment: The actuall issue is all the three regular expressions (regex) in swich condition are wrongly typed... Please correct them...

Comment: You should use `momentjs`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkValidDate(dateValue)
{
  var dateFormat="d-m-Y";
  switch(dateFormat)
  {
     case "d-m-Y":
     var regex = /^([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]([1-9]|1[012])[- /.]\d\d$/;
          if(dateValue.match(regex))
              return true;
           else
              return false;
     break;

     case "m-d-Y":
     var regex = /^([1-9]|1[012])[- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]\d\d$/;
          if(dateValue.match(regex))
              return true;
           else
              return false;  
      break;

    case "Y-m-d":
     var regex = /^\d\d[- /.]([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.]([1-9]|1[012])$/;
          if(dateValue.match(regex))
              return true;
           else
              return false;  
      break;
    default:
        return false;
      break;
  }
}
```

I have changed the regex little bit to support the format that you have told. Hope this help you.

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Suvethan/z9frygup/)

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems here.

- In amount of code provided - not self testable example
- At definition - what is d-m-Y?
- Possibly at regex, depending on former point.
- But the biggest problem is in approach.

Does switch using dateFormat work?

Is d-m-Y in fact dd-mm-YYYY? 
In that case, 1st regex (didn't test beyond that - no point) is wrong. This one will work:

```
case "d-m-Y":
var regex = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\-\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\-\-]\d{4}$/;
```

Using regex for this is not enough. You gonna need way more complex regex to filter out dates like 31-2-year, or years that have or not have 29-2 for example.

Your best bet is to use MomentJS. It's simple, not lightweight and battle-tested with good documentation.